# are c++ pointers to user-defined objects thread safe for reading?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, thread-safety

I can't find the answer but it's a simple question:

Is it safe for two threads to read the value of a pointer to a user-defined object in c++ at the same time with no locks or any other shenanigans?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. Actually it is safe to *read* any values (of builtin type) concurrently.

Data races can only occur, if a value is modified concurrently with some other thread using it. The key statements from the Standard for this are:

A *data race* is defined in §1.10/21:

> The execution of a program contains a data race if it contains two
>   conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not
>   atomic, and neither happens before the other.

where *conflicting* is defined in §1.10/4:

> Two expression evaluations conflict if one of them modifies a memory
>   location (1.7) and the other one accesses or modifies the same memory
>   location.

So you must use suitable synchronization between those reads and any writes.

Answer (score 4):

It is always safe to **read** values from multiple threads. It's only when you're also writing to the data that you need to manage concurrent accesses.

The only possible issue for read-only data is ensuring that the value has, in fact, been initialized when the reading is done. If you initialize the value before you start your threads you'll be fine.

Comment: It's not *always* safe to read values from multiple threads. Many CPUs use separate caches for each core, and as a result changes to a value on one core may not be visible in another. `volatile` does not resolve this issue, and as a result you ***must*** use explicit loading and storing (wonderfully provided by std::atomic<>). And despite the parameters of the question, there are *always* writes to a value, even if it's just initialization and deletion.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells - again: if **all** you're doing is reading, you **don't** need synchronization, except to ensure that the value has been initialized. Initializing before you start any threads takes care of this.

Comment: That corollary should be the *first* thing in your answer, lest someone skimming (like me) mistake what you're saying. I have proposed an edit to that end.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells - engineering is based on **understanding**, not on **skimming**.

Comment: @PeteBecker: You assume everyone is as comprehensive as you are, and that's a bad assumption. Be **clear** about what you're saying first and foremost. As I stated, it's not *always* safe to read from multiple threads. It's safe ***if*** you initialize the values first. Your very first statement is in direct opposition to your final.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't think I can be blamed for having a knee-jerk reaction to a statement like 'It's always safe to read values from multiple threads' when you yourself later note that, no, you have to initialize the values first. You might as well have been saying that it's perfectly reasonable to use a volatile boolean for thread synchronization.

Comment: Sorry but no, Soup d'Campbells, those statements are by far not equal.

Comment: @Soupd'Campbells: Knee-jerk reactions can always be blamed. You should actually, *gasp*, read the answer before you go on a tirade against it.

Comment: @doomster What statements? The statement that it's *always safe to read from multiple threads* and *always safe to read from multiple threads **if** the variables are initialized first*? Because you're spot on about that: they're not equal. Adding an exception kind of precludes the use of "always".

Comment: @GManNickG: And perhaps you should actually read my comment before you go on a tirade about that. My comment was **not** a tirade, it was an attempt at clarifying the behaviour of CPUs when reading values. The fact that it's even become a discussion is proof that it needs clarification, because as I've already pointed out, it is ***NOT*** always safe to read values from multiple threads.

Comment: Seriously, chill! You are arguing about minor linguistic details and doing so in a way that only serves to make yourself look like a raving lunatic. In particular, you're not in a position to dictate that people write "under the precondition A, you can do B" instead of "you can do B, if you make sure that A is met". On a technical level there is not even any disagreement, but you're too busy spitting venom to even notice that.

Answer (score 1):

It is generally not thread-safe if the variable gets modified in one of the threads.

Answer (score 1):

By thread-safe I suppose you mean to ask whether they have atomic writes. In C++03 this is not true, as C++03 doesn't really know about threads. In C++11 you have [std::atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), which is specialized for pointers.

Comment: He clearly indicated that it's _reads_ that he's interested in.

Comment: Not atomic writes. If I've got a pointer on the stack and two threads have got the address of that pointer and just want to read its value over and over, will that cause any problems?

Comment: @paul13243546: There are always writes to a value, even if it's just initialization and deletion. Modern CPUs use different caches for different cores; as a result, changes to a value may not be noticed in one core or another. Use std::atomic<> if it's going to be accessed from multiple threads.